# Perl: How to user regex for replacement in file?

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on a script which will read this file containing measurements in Angstroms and will convert them into nm(1 angstrom = 0.1 nm).

Following are some examples, it should find and replace:

```
3A

12 A

2.75 angstroms

0.123 Angstroms
```

It should not alter the following examples:
I like the number 3. A very nice number.There are 27 Aardvarks in London Zoo.

This is what i got so far. There are 2 things i have problem with, How i can perform that "devide by 10" after a match is found and write it back to the file? I just don't have any idea how the regex should look like for this question.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'angstrom.txt';   

open(FILE, $filename) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

open(FILE, ">$filename") or die "Can't write to $filename: $!";
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if($line =~ s/\d{2}\w//e)
    {   
        print FILE (@lines); 
    }
}
close(FILE);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. While your question is on-topic and actually shows effort, it reads a lot like homework, which it probably is. I think you should [edit] and change the question to simply show example input and desired output, explain what you want to capture and where you are struggling, but get rid of the assignment. That will probably get you a way better reception here. Stuff that yells _homework_ right in the front usually is not well received, even if the question is actually good.

Comment: Besides that, I would recommend to split your problem into two things. First, write code that takes known input and converts it to known output. Ignore the file operations, just print to the screen. Once you have that working, use it with the data that you read from the input file, and write the results to the output file. It will be way easier to verify what you are doing, and you will not get stuck on two different problems at once.

Comment: It is but i'm not asking for the whole code here, i just want to know how can i write a Regex that find something like 12A and replace it with (12/10)nm. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with regular expressions is - they aren't all that good at 'understanding' a numeric value. They're about text.

You can do it in this specific case, because you're dividing by 10, but I wouldn't normally call it a good idea.

So instead - extract the value to change, and apply a multiplication to it:

```
s|([\d\.]+) angstroms|$1 / 10 . " nm"|eig;
```

This will capture the 'digit+decimals' preceeding the word 'angstrom', divide by 10, and then add in 'nm' instead.

- The `i` flag makes the match case insensitive.
- The `e` flag says to 'evaluate' the replacement as perl.
- The `g` to do it "globally" per line - this may be irrelevant based on your sample data.

Note - we also use `|` instead of the more common `/` delimiter, because we use `/` in the expression. (You could escape it, but I think this is clearer)

So to do this to your file - we can make use of a [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) flag `-i` - inplace edit. (Specify an extension after - it renames source to that extension, and then rewrites the file in place)

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's|([\d\.]+) angstroms|$1 / 10 . " nm"|eig' angstrom.txt
```

Or you could splice the above into your code.

I would normally suggest avoiding a 'read-write' operation like that, because it does mean that a code glitch means you lose your source data. Open a new output file, and write to it - and then rename it once you're finished (successfully) is a better practice.

(It also consumes memory proportionate to your source file. This is often a non-issue, but can sometimes become relevant).

Given your code needs to match A, Angstrom or Angstroms (I assume you have no 'amps' to worry about?)

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's|([\d\.]+)\s*a(?:ngstroms)?\b|$1 / 10 . " nm"|ei'  angstrom.txt
```

This goes the extra step of matching `a`, `A`, `angstroms` or `Anstroms`, and we have `\b` to require a word break immediately after. So "12 Apples" won't catch us out.

Perhaps ironically - `-i.bak -pe` actually is probably easier than writing it longhand. However if you were to want to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'angstrom.txt';   

open(my $input, '<', $filename) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
open(my $output, '>', $filename.".new" ) or die $!; 

select $output; 
while ( <$input> ) {
    s|([\d\.]+)\s*a(?:ngstroms)?\b|$1 / 10 . " nm"|eig;
    print;
}
close ( $input );
close ( $output );

#rename .new here
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you put into writing such a detailed answer.

Comment: @sorbrique Your every answer have very clear explanation. I had a doubt , Is any need to close the file handle while using select?